# How do I append text to a text area in a Java program?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, append

I have a text area called text_ref. I need to append text to it, not over write it. Similar to a log, where text is appended to the log, and never overwritten. How do I append text to it? I am currently using "setText".

```
text_ref.setText(nationality + "is the nationality...");
```

Comment: There is append() method available.

Comment: -1 one look at the documentation would have given the answer. I can understand it's sometimes hard to find what you're looking for if the method's name is something cryptic but man, `append()` is the *first method* in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Use `append` method

```
text_ref.append(nationality + "is the nationality...");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `append` method passing the String literal, which need to be appended

```
  text_ref.setText(nationality + "is the nationality...");
  text_ref.append("I am just appending here to the current text");
```

Answer (score 0):

To append text in JTextArea child object you have to use the append method of this object.

```
text_ref.append("some text to append");
```

or

```
nationality = "Polish";
text_ref.append(nationality);
```